# Power BI query is not visible in BigQuery query history

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi

More of a curiosity question really. I load data into Power BI report from Google BigQuery (using native Google BigQuery connector in Power BI). All works fine, but for some reason I don't see this query in BigQuery's query history.

Did anyone experience something similar and knows the reason why this happens or how to change that (if at all possible)?

If I do exactly the same thing but using simba ODBC connector, I see this query in BigQuery's query history as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Never seen that before. I am always able to find the query history no matter what 3rd party connection I used.  Could you confirm the GCP service-account or auth-account and the GCP project for BQ job query that you used for your native Google BigQuery connector in Power BI?

Please make sure you have the access to the query history of that GCP account in that BQ job project.

Comment: Yeah I also thought it doesn't make sense. When I create a connection in PBI I authenticate with my google user account which also has admin access to BQ. I will look into whether it works with different accounts.
About access to query history, is there a special access that need to be granted? I thought it's part of the admin for BQ. 
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Hi, you could always access your own account query history. if you want to access query of other accounts, you would need to `bigquery.jobs.listall`.